# What is the length of the intercept made by the parabola ${ y }^{ 2 }=4x$ on the line $x+y=3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

I did not understand what is meant by length of intercept? Isn't intercept the point where the line cuts the axis? How can a point have a length? The answer given for length of intercept is $8\sqrt { 2 } $

Comment: You will find two points of intersection and have to find the distance between them. "Intercept" is a name for where the line meets the axes, and can mean this when unqualified, but here it is qualified by naming the parabola as the curve which is intersected by the line.

Comment: I think they mean the length of the _chord_, in other words, the distance between the points of interception.

Comment: The parabola $y^2=4x$ and the line $x+y=3$ have two interceptions, $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$. 
The length of the interception is the distance between $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$, which you can calculate using the Pythagorean theorem.